# Using map_dfr() with list of dates

Tags: r, purrr

Is there a way to use `purrr::map_dfr()` to run a function on a list of dates of varying lengths/missingness?

So far, I am able to do this with `map`, then `enframe`, then `unnest`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

date_list <- list(as.Date('2020-01-01'),
     c(as.Date('2021-01-01'), as.Date('2021-06-01')),
     NA_Date_,
     c(as.Date('2022-01-01'), as.Date('2022-08-01')),
     as.Date('2023-01-01')) 

map(date_list, max) |> 
  enframe(value = "latest") |> 
  unnest(cols = "latest") |>
  select(latest)
#> # A tibble: 5 × 1
#>   latest    
#>   <date>    
#> 1 2020-01-01
#> 2 2021-06-01
#> 3 NA        
#> 4 2022-08-01
#> 5 2023-01-01
```

However, using the more concise `map_dfr` returns the following error:

```r
map_dfr(date_list, max, .id = "latest")
#> Error in `dplyr::bind_rows()`:
#> ! Argument 1 must be a data frame or a named atomic vector.
#> Backtrace:
#>     ▆
#>  1. └─purrr::map_dfr(date_list, max, .id = "latest")
#>  2.   └─dplyr::bind_rows(res, .id = .id)
#>  3.     └─rlang::abort(glue("Argument {i} must be a data frame or a named atomic vector."))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want `purrr::map_vec()`?

```r
library(purrr)

date_list <- list(
  as.Date('2020-01-01'),
  c(as.Date('2021-01-01'), as.Date('2021-06-01')),
  lubridate::NA_Date_,
  c(as.Date('2022-01-01'), as.Date('2022-08-01')),
  as.Date('2023-01-01')
) 

map_vec(date_list, max)
#> [1] "2020-01-01" "2021-06-01" NA           "2022-08-01" "2023-01-01"

tibble::tibble(latest = map_vec(date_list, max))
#> # A tibble: 5 × 1
#>   latest    
#>   <date>    
#> 1 2020-01-01
#> 2 2021-06-01
#> 3 NA        
#> 4 2022-08-01
#> 5 2023-01-01
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-18 with [reprex v2.0.2.9000](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you! This is more efficient than the map, enframe, unnest approach I was using.

Answer (score 1):

Note that each resulting element of `map_df` should be a dataframe. Then it can combine these dataframes into on dataframe. Below is a solution. Just to point out, note that `map_df` `map_dfr` `map_dfc` and their equivalent 2 inputs ie `map2_df` etc have been superseded. Read the help page on these functions.

```
map_df(date_list, ~tibble(latest = max(.x)))

# A tibble: 5 × 1
  latest    
  <date>    
1 2020-01-01
2 2021-06-01
3 NA        
4 2022-08-01
5 2023-01-01
```

Comment: Thank you, while this is helpful, I don't believe that `map_df` requires inputs to be data frames - they can be lists or atomic vectors as well. The solution you provided here works, but it's computationally inefficient. I've noted that `map_dfr` has been superseded for `map` and `list_rbind()`, so I will need to look into that.